# How could discipline be used to aim weapons?

Tags: skills, dresden-files

My friend is a cryomancer and is arguing  using Discipline to aim Guns,  is this possible? Maybe as a stunt or something.  It would be like the inverse of using Guns to aim an enchanted item effect instead of Discipline.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Stunts

I would argue that this falls perfectly under the application of stunts - using one skill in place of another. From *Your Story* p.147:

> The first possible use for a stunt is to broaden a skill by giving it a new trapping. Often this is a trapping that’s “transplanted” from one skill to another. Sometimes this trapping may need to be modified, or made more circumstantial, in order to fit its new skill.

But the question I still have is, what is the fictional justification for this? Why should someone with the ability to hold together complex mental constructs be better at putting a bullet in a particular place? The price of a stunt (refresh) I think is a fair price for this ability, especially if it is in constrained circumstances:

- *Can use Discipline to fire a gun when...* or
- has another stunt (or two) as prerequisites ***Disciplined Shooter*** allows the character to fire a gun with Discipline, requires **Steady on the Draw**...

This is all provided a good answer to the above question can be worked out. Remember that Fate mechanics provide support for the fiction, not the other way around.

Comment: +1 one of the explicit applications of stunts is to substitute one skill for another.

Comment: You *could* use a stunt to substitute one skill for another in a single trapping (about 1/3 to 1/4 of all possible uses), but this is overpowered in the case of combat skills. Combat skills have one single important trapping (targeting), and one far-less-important trapping (evaluation). Using a stunt to copy 90% of the uses of a skill is abusing the skill-substitution stunts. +1 for "it should take more than one refresh to do this."

Comment: Using a stunt to transplant a single trapping may be really really useful, but it is also explicitly allowed by RAW, and is a reasonable thing for a player to do. The book suggests narrowing the use cases to clarify what is happening, so +1 for "Can use Discipline to fire a gun when..."

Comment: As for a discipline related narrative justification, there are always those movies and books where someone has a hail of bullets headed towards them, and they still take the time to make a well placed shot. 

That is a well disciplined character. Most people would fear for their life and seek cover. Maybe this character has a similar thought.

Comment: @KveldUlf - sure, exactly! The exact justification will inform the stunt. ***Sang Froid** - Can use Discipline to fire a gun when he has already taken fire* is a narrower application, and requires that that he not use the stunt when shooting first. My point is that this is a thing that Fate supports and condones and can be priced fairly using the system guidelines in DFRPG.

Comment: Or limit the usage.  e.g. ***Ice Water In My Veins** - Can use Discipline to fire a gun once per scene*.  The [Fate Stuntmaker](http://fate-srd.com/stunt-maker/) gives suggestions along these lines.

Comment: Another option for the stunt is to allow it to be used any time, but apply a negative effect as well.  If he is lining up a perfect shot perhaps that takes time and focus away from other things.  Maybe remove (or just lower) all defensive rolls on the round he uses the stunt, because he was so focused on lining up a perfect shot.  I like this because it allows an interesting 'glass cannon' build while still feeling more 'true' to the character concept by showing the downside of trying to aim so carefully in combat.

Comment: Or limit to only be used for *firing* a gun.  Then occasionally have the gun jam when it is narratively convenient, forcing them to either use their (presumably Average or Mediocre) Guns skill to clear it or change their tactics.

Answer (score 11):

**Don't**

You use the guns skill to use guns, its just that simple. Sounds like your friend/player is trying to get you to houserule something to make his character more powerful. Even using an aspect to do this would be too powerful and potentially game breaking.

Discipline the skill does not mean trigger-discipline. Its a representation of your character's mental discipline, whereas Guns is a representation of the mental and physical skill in firing and maintaining firearms.

Magic users in Dresden Files have access to incredibly powerful abilities, but that is offset by their low refresh and their tendency to not have as many skills as highly trained (and stunts) as a pure mortal would. At best I think he could give himself +2 to guns with a stunt that had some pre-req and flavor-wise matched his character.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought but he kept arguing. To clarify:There's no possible way that could happen, correct?

Comment: @moireth started writing out a big response, but then edited it into the answer, check it.

Comment: -1, since rules as written expressly contradicts this. I agree this looks like an attempt to powergame from what we can see in the question, but it's still legal. See Gomad's answer.

Comment: This isn't saying it's not legal, it's saying "don't." Just like in real life, being legal doesn't always mean something is a *good* idea in every situation.

Comment: Actually, this is saying it isn't legal. "At best I think he could give himself +2 to guns that had some pre-req and flavor-wise matched his character." Substitutions of skill trappings to another skill are expressly allowed. There is an argument that this is OP and should be houseruled, but answering a question about what the rules are with a houserule and having no mention of the actual rules are seems potentially problematic.

Comment: I don't like this answer.  FATE is about making cool characters and interesting stories above all else.  Yes allowing a 1 refresh stunt to always substitute discipline would be over powered, but that can be worked around.  Charge more refresh for the stunt, or (more likely) apply limits on when and how it can be used.  Completely refusing a cool idea entirely takes away the fun of FATE, find a way to make it fair and reward the player for creativity.  Remember Dresden is pretty competent with a gun, no reason other wizards shouldn't be every now and then

Answer (score 3):

### This is what spells are for!

One of the fundamental purposes of spells in DFRPG is to let you use your casting skills in place of any other more mundane skill, at the cost of time and stress. So while a mortal detective can only investigate a crime scene effectively if he's got ranks in the right skills, a wizard can investigate that crime scene just as effectively--if not more so--but it'll take him time to set up the ritual and cost him stress to cast it.

So a character *could* create a spell which lets him "aim the gun with zen-like focus" or whatever the player's justification is (I'm having a hard time seeing how a *cryomancer* can justify this). But it's a spell, with all the complications and costs that entails. Perhaps it'll be one of the rotes he learns.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one circumstance I can see Discipline being used to help with a firearm, and that's by using the **Combining Skills** rule from YS127.  This implies that the character is distracted or otherwise in a situation where his focus might wander.  While I did look at the Temporary Aspects for things like *Lying in Wait* or *Across my Sights* where a character waiting an extended period of time to snipe might need Discipline to stay in place, it quite clearly became more of a Combined roll.  The character would need Discipline to help/hinder their roll to stay perfectly still and trained on a target.

Otherwise this seems like a power gaming attempt with the little information about the situation in the question, and **should not be done**